# Shorthand private field caching of public property

Tags: c#, performance, lazy

I'm caching the value of a configuration object in a private field:

```
private Configuration _config;
public Congifuration Config { get { return _config = _config ?? GetConfig(); } }
```

`Config` is populated by reading a JSON file from disk, so performance is an obvious concern.

I like how concise this code is.

But I'm wary of assigning on every access. Should I be concerned about performance? And/or (in case I'm missing something) functionality?

Comment: You should be more concerned about posting hypothetical code. Here, we require real code, so if you have any then please post your real world solution.

Comment: I'll update with a real-world example

Comment: @t3chb0t I updated to make it slightly more concrete. If it's still too abstract, maybe another exchange (StackOverflow?) would be the place to go?

Comment: Mhmm... as a matter of fact, you could just use [`Lazy<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) for that or a shorter getter like `Config => _config ?? (_config = GetConfig());`

Comment: @t3chb0t true... I looked into that at one point. I think I passed over it because it's so verbose and seemed like overkill for my (single thread) applications. Maybe worth a second look though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about the on-topicness of this question, it's short but it seems to be fine... I'll risk getting downvoted...

---

As a matter of fact, you could just use [`Lazy<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) for that

```
.ctor
{
   _config = new Lazy<Configuration>(GetConfig);
}

public Congifuration Config => _config.Value;
```

or a shorter getter by using `=>`. Additionally you can put the assignment on the right side of the `??` so it takes place only once.

```
public Congifuration Config => _config ?? (_config = GetConfig());
```

I wouldn't, however, worry about the performance. Unless you call this property millions of times I bet you cannot even measure the difference of the assignment on left or the right side.

Comment: Thanks much. I should have researched more before posting. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901763/should-lazyt-be-preferred-to-lazy-initialization-in-a-getter/28901851#28901851) (and the associated question) express my concerns about the verbosity of `Lazy<T>` and the benefit of moving the assignment to the right of `??`. On-topic or not, this will help me write better code. If it's too off-topic, I'm sure the question will get closed. Thanks again!  :-)

Comment: `_config = new Lazy<Configuration>(GetConfig());` should probably be `_config = new Lazy<Configuration>(GetConfig);`; doesn't look very lazy otherwise ;)

Comment: @VisualMelon oh, right! Notepad coding :-) It would have been fine if I at least have written `() => GetConfig()`